# Django - Retrieve current user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-users

I am trying to retrieve the **current logged in user** using the following serializer:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def current_user(request):
    serializer = CurrentProfileSerializer(request.user)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

And this is the **CurrentProfileSerializer**:

```
class CurrentProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile # PROFILE MODEL HAS A ONE-TO-ONE FIELD WITH USER MODEL
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')
```

I am getting this Error when I am trying to go to the `current_user` **URL**:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on
>   serializer `CurrentProfileSerializer`. The serializer field might be
>   named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User`
>   instance. Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute
>   'user'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `Profile` instance to serializer, not `User`. Change your view to this:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def current_user(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return Response('User is not authenticated') 
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user) 
    serializer = CurrentProfileSerializer(profile)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: This works but gives an error when User is not logged in. `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'AnonymousUser'`

Comment: @SreekarMouli use login_required decorator: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

Comment: That changes the **url** to `accounts/login/?next=/api/reddit/current_user/`. I need more like an empty response or something close to that.

Comment: @SreekarMouli Then use `request.user.is_authenticated`. Check update.